# debugging with pre tags - angularjs/reactjs

Tags: angularjs, debugging, reactjs

I use pre tags extensively to debug my code in angular js, like so:

```
<pre>{{vm.names | json}}</pre>
```

Two questions:

1. how does this work under the hood?
2. is there an equivalent tool
   with reactjs that lets you see variables' values in the view, instead
   of the more common console.logs/debuggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add   `<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 4)}</pre>`   to the Component holding state to "visualize" the data in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<pre>` tags have nothing to do with debugging -- they are just HTML elements.

To break down what's happening in your HTML markup snippet:

- ` does some HTML formatting.
- Double Curly Braces `{{}}` indicate
  data binding. (Two-way, to be honest).
- `vm.names` is an object for that
  Controller (Without a fiddle, etc, I can't lay out the rest of the
  way it's instantiated)
- `| json` tells angular to filter vm.names
  using the [json
  filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json).

It looks as if React uses the DOM and a `.render` function. Have a look at their [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) page.

For how this works under the hood, you may want to read about [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#) and how it works, and also [Understanding Angular's $apply() and $digest()](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) to get a handle on angularjs model binding.